# How to Improve MariaDB 10.0.20 read/write performance than MySQL 5.1.43

Tags: mysql, database

MariaDB 10.0.20 performace is not good as compare to MySQL 5.1.43,

**What could be the affecting parameters like:**

- Memory
- Disks I/O
- CPU
- Filesystem
- Buffering

**How to identify Which parameter is impacting the performance?**

Here are some results of same queries which I run on both system:

**MySQL 5.1.43:**

**Total Memory:     16 GB**

```
[root@mysql]# time mysql -uroot -proot@12345 test_db < /tmp/tmp.sql
real    0m0.586s
user    0m0.010s
sys     0m0.045s
```

**MariaDB 10.0.20**:

**Total Memory:     35 GB**

```
[root@mysql]# time mysql -uroot -proot@12345 test_db < /tmp/tmp.sql
real    0m0.821s
user    0m0.024s
sys     0m0.022s
```

Here are innodb parameters from both MariaDB 10.0.20 and MySQL 5.1.43:

**MySQL Version: 5.1.43-log: =====>**

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES like '%innodb%';
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name                           | Value                  |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+
| have_innodb                             | YES                    |
| ignore_builtin_innodb                   | OFF                    |
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index              | ON                     |
| innodb_additional_mem_pool_size         | 1048576                |
| innodb_autoextend_increment             | 8                      |
| innodb_autoinc_lock_mode                | 1                      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size                 | 8388608                |
| innodb_checksums                        | ON                     |
| innodb_commit_concurrency               | 0                      |
| innodb_concurrency_tickets              | 500                    |
| innodb_data_file_path                   | ibdata1:10M:autoextend |
| innodb_data_home_dir                    |                        |
| innodb_doublewrite                      | ON                     |
| innodb_fast_shutdown                    | 1                      |
| innodb_file_io_threads                  | 4                      |
| innodb_file_per_table                   | OFF                    |
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit          | 1                      |
| innodb_flush_method                     |                        |
| innodb_force_recovery                   | 0                      |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout                | 50                     |
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog          | OFF                    |
| innodb_log_buffer_size                  | 1048576                |
| innodb_log_file_size                    | 5242880                |
| innodb_log_files_in_group               | 2                      |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir               | ./                     |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct              | 90                     |
| innodb_max_purge_lag                    | 0                      |
| innodb_mirrored_log_groups              | 1                      |
| innodb_open_files                       | 300                    |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout              | OFF                    |
| innodb_stats_on_metadata                | ON                     |
| innodb_support_xa                       | ON                     |
| innodb_sync_spin_loops                  | 20                     |
| innodb_table_locks                      | ON                     |
| innodb_thread_concurrency               | 8                      |
| innodb_thread_sleep_delay               | 10000                  |
| innodb_use_legacy_cardinality_algorithm | ON                     |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+
37 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_query_cache';
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| have_query_cache | YES   |
+------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache_size';
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| query_cache_size | 0     |
+------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Qcache%';
+-------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name           | Value |
+-------------------------+-------+
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 0     |
| Qcache_free_memory      | 0     |
| Qcache_hits             | 0     |
| Qcache_inserts          | 0     |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 0     |
| Qcache_not_cached       | 0     |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 0     |
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 0     |
+-------------------------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**MariaDB Version: 10.0.20-MariaDB-log: =====>**

```
MariaDB [cma_db]> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES like '%innodb%';
+-------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name                             | Value                  |
+-------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| ignore_builtin_innodb                     | OFF                    |
| innodb_adaptive_flushing                  | ON                     |
| innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm              | 10.000000              |
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index                | ON                     |
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index_partitions     | 1                      |
| innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay           | 150000                 |
| innodb_additional_mem_pool_size           | 8388608                |
| innodb_api_bk_commit_interval             | 5                      |
| innodb_api_disable_rowlock                | OFF                    |
| innodb_api_enable_binlog                  | OFF                    |
| innodb_api_enable_mdl                     | OFF                    |
| innodb_api_trx_level                      | 0                      |
| innodb_autoextend_increment               | 64                     |
| innodb_autoinc_lock_mode                  | 1                      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown       | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now               | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_filename               | ib_buffer_pool         |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances              | 8                      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort             | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup        | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_now               | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_populate               | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size                   | 16106127360            |
| innodb_change_buffer_max_size             | 25                     |
| innodb_change_buffering                   | all                    |
| innodb_checksum_algorithm                 | innodb                 |
| innodb_checksums                          | ON                     |
| innodb_cleaner_lsn_age_factor             | high_checkpoint        |
| innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled              | OFF                    |
| innodb_commit_concurrency                 | 0                      |
| innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct  | 5                      |
| innodb_compression_level                  | 6                      |
| innodb_compression_pad_pct_max            | 50                     |
| innodb_concurrency_tickets                | 5000                   |
| innodb_corrupt_table_action               | assert                 |
| innodb_data_file_path                     | ibdata1:12M:autoextend |
| innodb_data_home_dir                      |                        |
| innodb_disable_sort_file_cache            | OFF                    |
| innodb_doublewrite                        | ON                     |
| innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm          | backoff                |
| innodb_fake_changes                       | OFF                    |
| innodb_fast_shutdown                      | 1                      |
| innodb_file_format                        | Antelope               |
| innodb_file_format_check                  | ON                     |
| innodb_file_format_max                    | Antelope               |
| innodb_file_per_table                     | ON                     |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout               | 1                      |
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit            | 1                      |
| innodb_flush_method                       | O_DIRECT               |
| innodb_flush_neighbors                    | 1                      |
| innodb_flushing_avg_loops                 | 30                     |
| innodb_force_load_corrupted               | OFF                    |
| innodb_force_recovery                     | 0                      |
| innodb_foreground_preflush                | exponential_backoff    |
| innodb_ft_aux_table                       |                        |
| innodb_ft_cache_size                      | 8000000                |
| innodb_ft_enable_diag_print               | OFF                    |
| innodb_ft_enable_stopword                 | ON                     |
| innodb_ft_max_token_size                  | 84                     |
| innodb_ft_min_token_size                  | 3                      |
| innodb_ft_num_word_optimize               | 2000                   |
| innodb_ft_result_cache_limit              | 2000000000             |
| innodb_ft_server_stopword_table           |                        |
| innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree                 | 2                      |
| innodb_ft_total_cache_size                | 640000000              |
| innodb_ft_user_stopword_table             |                        |
| innodb_io_capacity                        | 200                    |
| innodb_io_capacity_max                    | 2000                   |
| innodb_kill_idle_transaction              | 0                      |
| innodb_large_prefix                       | OFF                    |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout                  | 50                     |
| innodb_locking_fake_changes               | ON                     |
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog            | OFF                    |
| innodb_log_arch_dir                       | ./                     |
| innodb_log_arch_expire_sec                | 0                      |
| innodb_log_archive                        | OFF                    |
| innodb_log_block_size                     | 512                    |
| innodb_log_buffer_size                    | 8388608                |
| innodb_log_checksum_algorithm             | innodb                 |
| innodb_log_compressed_pages               | ON                     |
| innodb_log_file_size                      | 268435456              |
| innodb_log_files_in_group                 | 2                      |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir                 | ./                     |
| innodb_lru_scan_depth                     | 1024                   |
| innodb_max_bitmap_file_size               | 104857600              |
| innodb_max_changed_pages                  | 1000000                |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct                | 75.000000              |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm            | 0.001000               |
| innodb_max_purge_lag                      | 0                      |
| innodb_max_purge_lag_delay                | 0                      |
| innodb_mirrored_log_groups                | 1                      |
| innodb_monitor_disable                    |                        |
| innodb_monitor_enable                     |                        |
| innodb_monitor_reset                      |                        |
| innodb_monitor_reset_all                  |                        |
| innodb_old_blocks_pct                     | 37                     |
| innodb_old_blocks_time                    | 1000                   |
| innodb_online_alter_log_max_size          | 134217728              |
| innodb_open_files                         | 4096                   |
| innodb_optimize_fulltext_only             | OFF                    |
| innodb_page_size                          | 16384                  |
| innodb_print_all_deadlocks                | OFF                    |
| innodb_purge_batch_size                   | 300                    |
| innodb_purge_threads                      | 1                      |
| innodb_random_read_ahead                  | OFF                    |
| innodb_read_ahead_threshold               | 56                     |
| innodb_read_io_threads                    | 8                      |
| innodb_read_only                          | OFF                    |
| innodb_replication_delay                  | 0                      |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout                | OFF                    |
| innodb_rollback_segments                  | 128                    |
| innodb_sched_priority_cleaner             | 19                     |
| innodb_show_locks_held                    | 10                     |
| innodb_show_verbose_locks                 | 0                      |
| innodb_simulate_comp_failures             | 0                      |
| innodb_sort_buffer_size                   | 1048576                |
| innodb_spin_wait_delay                    | 6                      |
| innodb_stats_auto_recalc                  | ON                     |
| innodb_stats_method                       | nulls_equal            |
| innodb_stats_modified_counter             | 0                      |
| innodb_stats_on_metadata                  | OFF                    |
| innodb_stats_persistent                   | ON                     |
| innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages      | 20                     |
| innodb_stats_sample_pages                 | 8                      |
| innodb_stats_traditional                  | ON                     |
| innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages       | 8                      |
| innodb_status_output                      | OFF                    |
| innodb_status_output_locks                | OFF                    |
| innodb_strict_mode                        | OFF                    |
| innodb_support_xa                         | ON                     |
| innodb_sync_array_size                    | 1                      |
| innodb_sync_spin_loops                    | 30                     |
| innodb_table_locks                        | ON                     |
| innodb_thread_concurrency                 | 8                      |
| innodb_thread_sleep_delay                 | 0                      |
| innodb_track_changed_pages                | OFF                    |
| innodb_undo_directory                     | .                      |
| innodb_undo_logs                          | 128                    |
| innodb_undo_tablespaces                   | 0                      |
| innodb_use_atomic_writes                  | OFF                    |
| innodb_use_fallocate                      | OFF                    |
| innodb_use_global_flush_log_at_trx_commit | ON                     |
| innodb_use_native_aio                     | ON                     |
| innodb_use_stacktrace                     | OFF                    |
| innodb_use_sys_malloc                     | ON                     |
| innodb_version                            | 5.6.24-72.2            |
| innodb_write_io_threads                   | 8                      |
+-------------------------------------------+------------------------+
147 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [cma_db]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_query_cache';
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| have_query_cache | YES   |
+------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [cma_db]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache_size';
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| query_cache_size | 0     |
+------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [cma_db]>  SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Qcache%';
+-------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name           | Value |
+-------------------------+-------+
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 0     |
| Qcache_free_memory      | 0     |
| Qcache_hits             | 0     |
| Qcache_inserts          | 0     |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 0     |
| Qcache_not_cached       | 0     |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 0     |
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 0     |
+-------------------------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**here is the result of strace -c -f -p $( pidof mysqld )**

```
    % time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 69.21    0.881874        2873       307           io_getevents
 15.38    0.195972        3999        49        18 futex
 11.53    0.146979        5444        27           select
  3.84    0.048993        8166         6         5 restart_syscall
  0.01    0.000167           0      1144           sendto
  0.01    0.000120           0      2304        18 recvfrom
  0.01    0.000114           0       628           time
  0.00    0.000054           0      7741           clock_gettime
  0.00    0.000014           1        21           stat
  0.00    0.000000           0        21           read
  0.00    0.000000           0        21           open
  0.00    0.000000           0        22           close
  0.00    0.000000           0        18           poll
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           pwrite
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           access
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           sched_yield
  0.00    0.000000           0        23           madvise
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           accept
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           shutdown
  0.00    0.000000           0         2         1 setsockopt
  0.00    0.000000           0         4           fcntl
  0.00    0.000000           0         5           fsync
  0.00    0.000000           0       122           gettimeofday
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           io_submit
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    1.274287                 12474        42 total
```

Comment: What is in tmp.sql?

You'd do well gathering statistics:

   SET PROFILING = 1;
   <your queries>
   SHOW PROFILES;
   SHOW PROFILE for QUERY n;

Comment: tmp.sql is list of queries which I execute.  total queries are more than 1000 , but "show profiles", shows  last 15 query duration. 

Here issue is not related query optimization, because on both server same queries are running and  time taken by them is different.

Comment: You're not interested in query optimization, but you **are** interested in seeing **where** the queries use their time. Another possibility on Linux is to run `strace -c -f -p $( pidof mysqld )` to see which system calls use the most time. There is no "optimal" setup which is valid for whatever query, because if there was, it would long since have become the default. You need to tune your setup to your actual activity. Another thing to verify would be whether all the queries take roughly the same time, and if not, which are the most responsible for the wallclock time. Then you investigate why.

Comment: We're back to discussing your queries. Are you using transactions? (Have you tried wrapping the SQL file into a transaction?). How large is your binlog? For small values, `innodb_flush_method` might be better set at `fsync` or `O_DSYNC`.

Comment: I have added strace result in above question, 
I don't know where to find the binlog, I checked the mysql log dir, but it was not there. 
`[root@mysql]# ll -h /data/mysql/mysql-bin.000002
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 1.8K Jul 23 04:58 /data/mysql/mysql-bin.000002`   we are using `O_DSYNC` method

Comment: you seems to be comparing same query on both database, but as I see you probably are not using same machine? even if you are using same machine are you sure that data folder for both database are not same and there is no conflict in them and both are on same hardware and tests are run when the load is similar. can you confirm that.

Comment: Er, no. Judging from what you posted, you're using O_DIRECT: `| innodb_flush_method                       | O_DIRECT               |`

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment, so I'm trying to lay down enough for it to be considered the answer it can't be.

**TL;DR** there is no one-size-fits-all configuration that will optimize performances. You need to [tailor the configuration to your system, OS, file system, and actual operations](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/optimization-and-tuning/).

In general the various RDBMS operations are divided into CPU- and memory- bound as well as I/O bound, with different degrees of concurrency. The config settings will always be a compromise between conflicting needs, and the weight assigned to those needs varies from query to query.

Given that you're interested in speeding up **overall** operations, the first step will be to determine **what queries cause the longest delays**.

Choosing a setting that accelerates 99% per cent of your queries making them twice as fast, and slows down the remaining 1% by as little as ten per cent, might seem great... yet turn out to be *counterproductive* if that one per cent of your queries was actually responsible for 95% of wallclock time. You halve 5% to 2.5%, and increase 95% to 104.5%; the net result is a speed decrease of 7%, in accordance with [Amdahl's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law).

That is why there is a slow-log in MySQL/XtraDB/Percona/MariaDB: because you 
*almost always* need to speed up the *slowest* queries first (you actually want to speed up those queries for which the product time * times_executed is largest. Usually these are not numerically the dominating queries - there's [another interesting observation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle) in that - and you can garner large rewards by optimizing relatively few, well-chosen queries).

Once you know which queries are those, you can check their indexing, see whether the schema might be optimized for a given database, whether they could benefit by caching and so on. The SQL structure being the same does **not** mean that MySQL and MariaDB will be equally efficient in dealing with it. You *might* discover that running

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable PROCEDURE ANALYSE();
```

gives a different `Optimal_fieldtype` value for a column. And the same goes for indexing.

Even a simple reordering of the queries (if possible) might give you a benefit on one database, and a loss on another, if they hit differently the file system caches.

A different approach would be to focus on those low level functions shared by all queries (loading data from disk, saving data to disk, flushing, etc.).

You want to load as little data as possible (hence covering indexes...), and save as little data as possible. Disabling implicit transactions and handling them explicitly can yield huge returns.

You also want to flush data as seldom as possible -- but no more than that (there's data integrity to consider).

For example in MariaDB the value `O_DIRECT` for `innodb_flush_method` is not necessarily the fastest (see [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23943/innodb-flush-method-o-direct-vs-o-dsync-performance-impact-on-ext3-with-lvm-disk)), depending on things such as
 - the filesystem (ext3, ext4, ...)
 - the actual hardware (no RAID, WT RAID, WB RAID, WB w/cache...)
 - the support (SSD, RIO, HDD, SAN, ...)
 - the actual data load

Also, the various MySQL forks implementing not all the same features, they may not be directly comparable, nor scale as well. A really small database might run way faster on a MySQL MyISAM setup than on a full-fledged XtraDB InnoDB setup; while the opposite might be (and almost certainly *is*) true for a huge database with massive concurrent accesses.

E.g. with the [Percona](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.6/scalability/innodb_io.html#innodb_flush_method) fork,

> - fdatasync: use fsync() to flush both the data and log files.
> - O_SYNC: use O_SYNC to open and flush the log files; use fsync() to flush the data files.
> - O_DIRECT: use O_DIRECT to open the data files and fsync() system call to flush both the data and log files.
> - O_DIRECT_NO_FSYNC: use O_DIRECT to open the data files but don’t use fsync() system call to flush both the data and log files.
>     **This option isn’t suitable for XFS file system**.
> - ALL_O_DIRECT: use O_DIRECT to open both data and log files, and use fsync() to flush the data files but not the log files. This
>     option is recommended when InnoDB log files are big (more than 8GB),
>     **otherwise there might be even a performance degradation**. Note: When
>     using this option on ext4 filesystem variable innodb_log_block_size
>     should be set to 4096 (default log-block-size in ext4) in order to
>     avoid the unaligned AIO/DIO warnings.

Comment: Here are some comparison between 2 system:  
`MySQL 5.0.43:` CentOS release 5.6 (Final), RAM: 16GB, Total processor: 15, cpu cores: 4, filesystem: ext3, not using any innodb_flush_method it's blank
`MariaDB 10.0.20:`CentOS release 6.6 (Final), RAM: 35GB, Total processor: 5, cpu cores: 1, filesystem: ext4, innodb_flush_method:O_DIRECT 

Here Memory is not issue and CPU are not issue, for above MySQL run it doesn't reaches to 30% utilization for both cases  
`DISC I/O:` How do I measure how fast the physical disk can move to access the data on both system?

Comment: As said on MariDB site filesystem is not a issue. I don't know Disabling swap will improve performance drastically, as on both system databases are same and same queries are getting fire. About buffer I already shared the "innodb" parameters on both system. I want to find out the exact impacting parameters on MariDB system. Let me how do I track it as both database tables, indexes and queries are same on both system. Also slow query is not an issue here, queries are simple here.